# router not responding for a few minutes?

Tags: networking, router

I'm encountering a couple of time a what seems to be an internet deconnection.
Basicaly for a couple of minutes I can't access internet then everything get fine for a couple of hours.

I thought initial it was a connection problem and contacted my provider, but it says there is no problem and then can't see any deconnection.

What's weird is that when I try to connect on the route(192.168.1.1), it's not working either.
I can't connect to the router until the "internet" problem is sorted.

I thought it was a WIFI problem but I have the same symptoms using a cable.
Therefore it seems that it is the router which is not responding for a few minutes.

Any one as any idea what it could be and how to check what is the problem and how to solve it ?

Also, when I look at the log and the router, there is usually a 'kernel intrusion' message around that time. Is that possible that a port scan attack can slow down the router enough so it's inresponsive ?

Comment: I've had this problem a number of times with routers that were at the end of their lifespan. I've also encountered it on networks where a bittorrent user was using a blocklist. connections severed by the blocklist were stuck in a half established state, filling up the state tables on the router, and preventing any new connections until some of the existing severed connections time out and are forgotten by the router. A `kernel intrusion` doesn't make me think of a port scan so much as a DOS attack. what kind of router do you have?

Comment: Maybe it's DOS attach indeed. It's a `Tenda W300D`